# php listener page

Tags: php, listener

So I've been strugling with this for two days now with not a whole lot of success.

What I'm getting is an http POST generated by a webpage that is being sent to a php file that I'm working on creating on my server. So basically I'm trying to create a php listener script that when an http post occurs it will run the script save the xml data into a SimpleXMLElement so that I can write a MYSQL query to import the data into our database. Once I get the data into a SimpleXMLElement, I can take over from there, the issue i'm having is that I cannot get the listener.php file to listen to the HTTP POST and read the data into a local file.

```
<?php
public void RunServer()
{
    var prefix = "http://*:4333/";
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
try
{
    listener.Start();
}
catch (HttpListenerException hlex)
{
    return;
}
while (listener.IsListening)
{
    var context = listener.GetContext();
    ProcessRequest(context);
}
listener.Close();
}

private void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context) 
{
// Get the data from the HTTP stream
var body = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
$data = body
byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ACK");
context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
context.Response.KeepAlive = false;
context.Response.ContentLength64 = b.Length;

var output = context.Response.OutputStream;
output.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
context.Response.Close();
}
?>
```

This code is the closest I've gotten to what I need and I get a 500 error when I try to access the page. I'm not going to lie I'm pretty new to php and am having issues understanding function definitions. (Also I did get this code from a StackOverflow ticket that was closed)

I'm currently using php5 and apache on my server for my web hosting. ]
I have a php.info() file setup and can post it if need be.

Comment: The code is not php. When you try to run it through the php parser, it will fail with a "Fatal Error". You are probably seeing a 500 error, because your server hides that php error from you.

Comment: I had a slight feeling that this was going to be the case seeing as the variable declarations were different from the ones I had been seeing prior. I.E. when I wrote my sql script in php, but i wasn't sure. Is there a way to do this in php that you would recommend?

Comment: Your code seems to be a mashup of PHP, JavaScript, and some C variant. What StackOverflow question did this code come from?

Comment: This is the thread that the code came from. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004616/how-to-use-httplistener-to-receive-http-post-which-contain-xml

Comment: You don't need to "listen" for an http post if you are running Apache. Your webserver is already doing the listening, and when the POST request arrives it will deal with it by sending it to the PHP file specified. Your code is not PHP, and so there is no way the server is going to be able to run it. Look in the PHP manual about the $_POST superglobal for examples of how to use it.

Comment: That answer is in C#, not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save data into a SimpleXMLElement that will do it:

```
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($_POST['xml-value-field']);
//insert into mysql db...
//write to local file...
?>
```

Comment: Thanks to @GarekhL I was able to try that to no avail and I ran the code '$xml = file_get_contents(php://input) and instead of getting xml data, i got something that looked like this.    %3D%22AltCustID%22+CustomerPO%3D%22PO12345%22%3E%0D%0A%09++%3CPayment+Method%3D%22invoice%22